# Object Relational Features of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, object-relational-model

Does anyone know a good reference to look into what Object Relational features are available in SQL Server (any version)? I found a really good summery for [Oracle](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-objects.html) but all I can find for SQL Server is information about LINQ to SQL, which is good stuff, but I'm looking for more power in the database like defined types, nested tables, etc.

I know you can use CLR types in SQL Server, and that would be interesting to me too, I just am looking for a good place to read about all the OR features it has.

PS.  I'm willing to purchase a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [Best Practices for Semantic Data Modeling for Performance and Scalability](http://sqlcat.com/whitepapers/archive/2008/09/03/best-practices-for-semantic-data-modeling-for-performance-and-scalability.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, that looks interesting.   *printing*

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server is not as object relational as one might expect - not that long ago I realized that it does not (even) support table inheritance.

Comment: That's what it seems like to me, but I was hoping I was wrong and just couldn't find information about it because no one in academia uses it.

Comment: Coming from PostgreSQL I couldn't believe that, too. But I searched hard, read a lot, talked to some cohorts, and am quite confident now, that MS SQL does at least not support table inheritance.